# Python how to accept a request to telegram group

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

How to accept requests to the private group with telebot automatically?

I tried with chat_join_request_handler, but I got a error. But in documentary it's True.

I need to get such code in some strings. Thank's a lot for your answers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.